# Get TextContent from OuterHtml

Tags: c#, anglesharp

`Textcontent` is returning text without spaces in some cases (I'm using console app), so I want to make sure it does. I want to know if there is a way to Replace every `<br>` with a new line, and then get the TextContent from that modified OuterHTML?

```
  var posts_value = Posts.Select(m => m.OuterHtml.Replace("<br>",Environment.NewLine));
```

I'm getting the desired results, but not sure how can I get the TextContent from the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are looking for a string that is closer to the text rendered by a browser then try the `GetInnerText` extension method coming with AngleSharp.Css.

If all you want is to get `TextContent` with the replacement mentioned in the OP then I would suggest making Node replacements and then getting the `TextContent`.

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var config = Configuration.Default;
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
    var document = await context.OpenAsync(res => res.Content("<div>hello<br>there</div>"));
    var before = document.Body.TextContent;
    
    foreach (var br in document.QuerySelectorAll("br"))
    {
        br.Replace(document.CreateTextNode("\n"));
    }
    
    var after = document.Body.TextContent;
    
    before.Dump();
    after.Dump();
}
```

The result is

```
hellothere
hello
there
```

Hope that helps!